# How do you interpret "believes all things" in 1 Cor. 13:7?

Tags: greek, pauline-epistles

Robertson has:

> **Believeth all things** (παντα πιστευει [panta pisteuei]). Not gullible, but has faith in men.
> --
> Robertson, A. T. (1933). *Word Pictures in the New Testament* (1 Cor. 13:7). Broadman Press.

But, how do you interpret this phrase so that it doesn't imply gullible?

This is not an easy question to answer.  Even translating πιστεύει as *trust* isn't an easy answer.  John 2:24 seems to contradict 1 Cor. 13:7.

> But Jesus on his part did not entrust [ἐπίστευεν] himself to them, because he knew all people ... (John 2:24, ESV)

Comment: 1 COR 13:4-8: Christian ἀγάπη (charity, love) points to warmhearted affection and benevolence (cf. Strong's G26); specifically, how it:

1) πάντα στέγει πάντα (keeps secrets);

2) πάντα πιστεύει (believes in the good in every person);

3) πάντα ἐλπίζει (hopes for the best for all persons), and

4) πάντα ὑπομένει (endures all things).

Gullibility is always a problem with far too many Bible readers and pew-sitters who tend to believe or accept things per se without challenging them, making them more likely to trust others and be swayed by persuasive rhetoric or misleading information.

Comment: @Ferguson - Have you noticed that most misleading information, especially conspiracy theories, are not based on love, much less facts.

Comment: @Webb - indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Albert Barnes noticed the same thing and observes:

> **Believeth all things** - The whole scope of the connection and the argument here requires us to understand this of the conduct of others.
> It cannot mean, that the man who is under the influence of love is a
> man of "universal credulity;" that he makes no discrimination in
> regard to things to be believed; and is as prone to believe a
> falsehood as the truth; or that he is at no pains to inquire what is
> true and what is false, what is right and what is wrong. But it must
> mean, that in regard to the conduct of others, there is a disposition
> to put the best construction on it; to believe that they may be
> actuated by good motives, and that they intend no injury; and that
> there is a willingness to suppose, as far as can be, that what is done
> is done consistently with friendship, good feeling, and virtue. Love
> produces this, because it rejoices in the happiness and virtue of
> others, and will not believe the contrary except on irrefragable
> evidence.

One of my pet grievances with modern English versions is that almost always translate the Greek verb πιστεύω as "believe" rather than the closer meaning of "trust".  Thus, the NIV (slightly interpretively) render this phrase as, "always trusts".

That is, I suggest Paul is actually saying that a loving person always thinks the best of a person.  Trust engenders trust; a loving trusting person brings out the best in those around him/her.  As Barnes observes, there cannot be any suggestion of gullibility any more than "hopes all things" means that a person subscribes to every crack-pot suggestion they hear.

Thus, (as much as I do not like to admit it) in this occasion, the NIV gets closest to the intended meaning when it renders 1 Cor 13:7 as:

> It always protects, always trusts, always hopes, always perseveres.

The pulpit commentary also has something similar:

> **Believeth all things**. Takes the best and kindest views of all men and all circumstances, as long as it is possible to do so. It is the
> opposite to the common spirit, which drags everything in deteriorem
> partem, paints it in the darkest colours, and makes the worst of it.
> Love is entirely alien from the spirit of the cynic, the pessimist,
> the ecclesiastical rival, the anonymous slanderer, the secret
> detractor.

Comment: Dottard, another way to think of "believing all things" is as having given the benefit of the doubt until solid evidence is presented otherwise.  In their circumstances of that time there may have been a lot of back stabbing or gossip going on because of envy of the spiritual gifts each had.

Comment: @Gina - true - but I do not believe that  back stabbing, gossip and evny are confined to that time - such are still very common.

Comment: envy and gossip is always with us.  But the context of Paul's message was centering around love being greater than all the spiritual gifts they were arguing over.

Answer (score 1):

1 Corinthians 13 is the famous "faith, hope, and charity" chapter that everyone is familiar with.
Unfortunately some of the words have changed meaning over the years.

For instance "hope" doesn't have the wishful-thinking meaning that we use today, as in "*I hope I win the lottery tonight!*".
The original meaning involves a high degree of certainty about the future, as in "*I hope to graduate next year and then go on to law school.*".

Similarly the word translated here as "charity" doesn't have the same meaning we use it for today, such as giving to the poor.
As this chapter itself says in verse 3:

> And though I bestow all my goods to feed the poor, and though I give my body to be burned, *and have not charity*, it profiteth me nothing.

"Charity" is much better translated (as most new versions *do* translate the Greek "agapē) as "love", though in a larger and less personal way than might be assumed.

Consider the final verse of the chapter:

> And now abideth faith, hope, charity, these three; but the greatest of these is charity.

- **Faith** involves full acceptance and incorporation into our lives and thoughts.
  We have faith that the sun will rise tomorrow, that our hearts will continue beating, that gravity will keep us from floating away.
  We are aware of these things, but don't have to continually think about them; we take them for granted.
- **Hope** involves limited belief in things that we realize might not happen, but very likely will.
  We hope to keep our jobs, that our families will be safe, that our lives will continue tomorrow and next week much like they are now.
  We *do* often think about these things, but normally don't dwell on them.
- **Charity** (love for mankind) involves a forced belief in things that we know will probably not happen.
  We show this when we give money to someone "for a cup of coffee", even though we know it will likely be used for a different beverage.
  We know that there *is* a chance that it will help.

#### Faith, Hope, and Charity (universal love)

- Faith is hard to develop or obtain, but once one has it, it becomes very easy.
- Hope is how most people spend most of their thoughts, requiring some concern and some decision making.
- Charity is much more difficult, requiring that we sacrifice our time, money, etc. for something that is unlikely to do any good.

That's why Paul says charity is the greatest of the three, because we are willing to sacrifice for something that might, once in a while,
actually help another human being.

So when Paul says "*[Charity] Beareth all things, believeth all things, hopeth all things, endureth all things.*", he is pointing out *why* charity is so difficult.

The NLT version paraphrases this verse as:

> Love never gives up, never loses faith, is always hopeful, and endures through every circumstance.

- One will receive no recognition and will likely never know the result of the act of charity, for good or bad, but one persists.
- One must accept what seem to be obvious lies (giving money "for a cup of coffee"), but one knows that it *might* be true.
- One must act as if good *will* be the result, but one knows it will likely not do any good.
- One will fail or even be subject to abuse ("I don't like mayonnaise on sandwiches!" [throws it back at you]), but one continues.

Comment: But has "all things" changed meaning?

Comment: @PerryWebb, It's the word "charity" that has changed. "*believes all things*" indicates a personal attitude to the other person. Intellectually one knows that "for a coffee" is almost certainly a lie, but with "agapē" one unconsciously pretends or acts as if blatant lies are true, There's a chance that it *is* true, and by believing the person, you are providing a chance to make it true. Perhaps that demonstration of love could be the tipping point that causes the person to start on the path to recovery. Yes, it's a form of gullibility, but one that is deliberately and knowingly effected.

Answer (score 1):

Trust without gullible is a wisdom from God.

In the parable of the Lost Son (Luke 15:11-32), the father knew the younger son will take the money for his extravagance. Why would he permit his request?

Consider if the father didn't give him the money, the son would still leave, spent everything he had but never came back to his father, for he had hatred in his heart. The father gave him the money was to buy a hope, that he would return.

Therefore to the son, the father appeared to trust him, sharing him the estate while still live. In fact, the father was not gullible, and the son didn't notice, that his father had prepared his miserable return.

This is LOVE, trust but not gullible, which is the same God do to us. He knows our human race will be fallen, yet he had prepared the mystery (Ephesians 3:3-9) since the creation.

**Without Trust, there is no beginning.**

Answer (score 1):

### Love Believes All Things Promised by God

The verse is more easily understood in context.

> 4 Love is patient, love is kind and is not jealous; love does not brag
> and is not arrogant, 5 does not act unbecomingly; it does not seek its
> own, is not provoked, does not take into account a wrong suffered, 6
> does not rejoice in unrighteousness, but rejoices with the truth; 7
> bears all things, believes all things, hopes all things, endures all
> things.

First, the Epistle lists several characteristics that do *not* typify love, such as jealousy, arrogance, being provoked, getting even, etc. To these qualities the author (Paul) posits several things that love indeed does, each ending with "all things." They are not meant to be taken literally, but are a type of [hyperbole used to heighten contrast with their opposites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole).

> Hyperbole is often used for emphasis or effect. In casual speech, it
> functions as an intensifier... The rhetorical
> device may be used for serious or ironic or comic effects.
> Understanding hyperbole and its use in context can help understand the
> speaker's point. Hyperbole generally conveys feelings or emotions from
> the speaker, or from those who the speaker may talk about.

**Depending on punctuation (which does not exist in the original), Paul concludes his list of what love does with the statement: "Love never fails." (vs. 8) We all surely know that love DOES fail at times, so this must be another hyperbole. Possibly it means True Love never fails or God's love never fails. But that is not what it says. Likewise "love believes all things" is not to be taken literally. It must mean something else, such as that love believes "all True Things" or more likely: "love believes all things promised by God."**

---

NOTE: In [Hyperbole and overstatement as tools for deeper Bible study](https://deeperstudy.com/hyperbole-and-overstatement-as-tools-for-deeper/), author Stephen Singleton discusses how recognizing hyperbole helps us to understand the Bible better.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is common among the commentaries when they addressed this question.  They struggled with it.  One thing that makes sense is Paul is not writing about one-sided love.  He is writing about two-sided love.  Love is not complete unless it is returned by the recipient.

> And we have come to know and to believe the love that God has for us. God is love, and the one who remains in love remains in God, and God remains in him.
>  In this, **love is perfected [τετελείωται, completed]** with us so that we may have confidence in the day of judgment, for we are as He is in this world.
> (1 John 4:16–17, ESV)

Love is not gullible when we trust the one who loves us back with the love Paul describes.  William Barclay hints on this in his commentary:

> *Love is completely trusting*. This characteristic has a twofold aspect. (1) *In relation to God*, it means that love takes God at his word, and can take every promise which begins ‘Whoever’ and say: ‘That means me.’ (2) *In relation to our fellow men and women*, it means that love always believes the best about other people. It is often true that we make people what we believe them to be. If we show that we do not trust people, we may make them untrustworthy. If we show people that we trust them absolutely, we may make them trustworthy.
> --
> Barclay, W. (2002). *The Letters to the Corinthians* (3rd ed., p. 145). Westminster John Knox Press.

Answer (score 0):

A little background first before I comment on the question.

First of all, we are not to believe every spirit which just goes to show, we are not to believe everything and the verse  in question must mean something else.

> Beloved do not believe every spirit, but test the spirits to see whether they are from God. 1 John 1:4

We also know that  1 Corinthians 13 is describing God's agape love.

God is The agape (love)
1 John 4:8

1 Corinthians 13:7 is a continuation of  describing God's and what He is like.
He's  also believes all.

It does not say all things, it says all.

> ◄ 3956. pas ►
> pas: all, every
> Original Word: πᾶς, πᾶσα, πᾶ

What does that mean? Love believes all?

So even believing comes from God, and is also an expression of Him and of His love.

> 1 Corinthians All encompassing
> Is forgoing all, is believing all, is expecting all is enduring all.
> With the words above Paul concludes his list of what “love” is. Here too it helps us to consider that the representation of love as a person actually refers to GOD himself, who is love. He is forgoing all because He believes in all He has spoken, like no one else. He knows that everything He promises will also be delivered absolutely. That is why He endures all the suffering of the present in which He also suffers. This verse speaks of GOD and the steadfastness of his Word and the power it gives to endure.
> Also note the four times “all”. GOD’s love is all encompassing and all in his Word is believable and hopeful. This love provides strength which can endure everything. A person always thinks about too small about GOD’s love. Because GOD’S love excludes nothing and nobody. And no circumstance is that difficult, or this love provides everything that is needed.
> What a superlative message in a dark world with such a lack of solid trust, hope and strength!   By Andre Piet

The example of the prodigal son comes to mind.  The Father always believed his son would return that's why he was waiting for him.

Believing is such a foundation of God, who believes and spoke His word.

This is what I've been pondering since Paul is encouraging the Corinthians  (and us as well who are in Christ) to build each other up in the faith by seeing through the flesh to Christ who dwells in believers.  Make that part of your pursuit in love.  Since God believes all are completed in Christ we too need to believe that of all as well.  Perhaps that is seeing the best in everybody in faith, in believing in all.

He knows us fully in Christ, he believes in His Son and His Son believes in Him and all who are in Him are now capable of believing in each other in Him.

Comment: πάντα is neuter plural meaning "all".  While "all" is plural in English, it has no gender, so translators translate πάντα as "all things".